# How to make validation with Jquery if there is ACTION within form?

Tags: jquery

I have tested the following validation script:
jQuery validation plug-in 1.7

1. How to make working validation error as I have to use action=""

Is there possibility as error is not working in this case.

1. Where is set id="cname" name="name"  within validation script?

   A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages

   Name
    ***

URL demo:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I kindly ask you to send me correct script that it will not be submitted data when     user refreshes form but only after validation is validated/confirmed.Should be form named by any ID? Example: myform1

I have currently as sample:

```
JQuery.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function(form) {
form.submit();
}
});
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(".myform1").validate({
rules: {
name: {
required: true,
},
messages: {
name: {
required: "Requested field",
}
);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control what the form does once the validation rules have been passed. To simply have the form submit the data to the form action, use:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```